# Three.js reverse lookAt(camera.position)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm tweening objects towards the camera and want them to face the camera when arriving, so I'm using `object.lookAt(camera.position)`

I now need to tween this object back to it's original rotation and I can't find a way of undoing this lookAt, i.e. it won't tween back to it's original rotation, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all check out the quaternion befor your object looks at towards camera position. 
with this piece of code.

`var myqt = your_Object.quaternion. (if it is an instance of mesh)`

fine, now our object is looking at the camera and. now check out the quaternions again.
i am sure you will find a different output.

now after performing the operation we need to get back to previous state.
so, just set the quaternions with that.

`myqt.quaternion.set(myqt);`

thanks :)